# Can python be set to perform a function only if a specific user in logged in?

Tags: python, html, mysql, sql, flask

I have created a sort of web-based help desk ticket system for my work. I used  flask for my python web frame work and also have a couple of SQL databases set up for user accounts as well as the help desk tickets. Right now, anyone that is logged in can delete the tickets. I would like to have it so that only a specific user account (such as mine) can delete the tickets. Is there some way to facilitate that within the function to delete the tickets? I had though if an if statement but am not sure the param to use.

Here is the function to delete the tickets and where I assume this needs to be done:

```
 # Delete Ticket


@app.route('/delete_ticket/<string:id>', methods=['POST'])
@is_logged_in
def delete_ticket(id):
    # Create cursor
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

    # Execute
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM tickets WHERE id = %s", [id])

    # Commit to DB
    mysql.connection.commit()

    # Close connection
    cur.close()

    flash('Ticket Deleted', 'success')

    return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
```

Comment: I don't know how your DB is structured but if you have a `user_id` column into `tickets` table you can execute a safer query like `DELETE FROM tickets WHERE id = %s AND user_id =%s`

Comment: Oh I had not thought of that. I don't have a user ID but I do have "username" which I assume would essentially be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you check if a user is logged in with `@is_logged_in`, you can have a similar decorator check for a particular role, such as `@is_admin`.

It's typically much better to assign user roles and check for these roles, than hardcode a check for a particular user's identity, since individual users join and leave often, but roles are relatively stable.